# name 'StandardScaler' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed `scikit-learn 0.23.2` via `pip3`, however, I get this error from my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pca_iris.py", line 12, in <module>
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
NameError: name 'StandardScaler' is not defined
```

I searched the web and saw similar topics, however the version is correct and I don't know what to do further. The line `import sklearn` is in the top of the script.

Any thought?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) is a method under `sklearn.preprocessing`. You need to import the [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

Or

```
import sklearn
X = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Right. I guessed `import sklearn` is enought. Thanks.

Comment: Made same mistakes myself before. You can use both ways but the first way is more common.